# Zeros and the sign of the function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is:
Determine the zero and sign of the function
$$
y=1-x+\sqrt{{x^3\over x+3}}
$$

I found that the function intersects $x$ axis in $\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $y$ in $1$. Is that right ?
How to find sign of the function ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $y=0$ then
$$
\begin{split}
x - 1 &= \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}} \\
x^{3/2} &= (x-1)\sqrt{x+3} \\
x^3 &= (x-1)^2(x+3) = x^3+x^2-5x + 3 \\
0 &= x^2-5x + 3 \\
\end{split}
$$
and the quadratic formula applies to give you two solutions.

At $x = 0$, your function is positive, and when you cross a zero (in either direction), it will change sign.

Can you finish?

Comment: whether the sign can be determined by solving inequalities $1-x+\sqrt{{x^3\over x+3}}>0 \land 1-x+\sqrt{{x^3\over x+3}}<0$ ?

Comment: @SrdjanPesevic you get the distribution of signs of your graph (i.e. where it is positive or negative) using the methodology in my answer. There are $3$ regions, into which $2$ roots divide the real line, and in neighboring regions, the signs differ. Compute the roots and see where $x=0$ fits.